# Why does the game count 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 instead of 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I start my Clickgame after I finish the first round, the seconds count 0,5,4,3,2,1 instead of 5,4,3,2,1. Does anyone know whats the mistake in the code and what to change? So it's like the 5 is counted double.

The other thing I want to know, how can I add a function (input HTML) to add a popup where user can choose their own time of seconds they want to play?

```js
let klick = 0;
display = document.querySelector('#time');

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
  $("#start").fadeOut(); //Der Startbutton geht weg
  $("#welcome").fadeOut(); // Das Willkommensschild geht weg

  $("#time").fadeIn(900); //Timer kommt 
  $("#clicker").animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }); //clicker wird gestartet 

  var dauer = 5;

  startTimer(dauer); //übergibt die variable dauer, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.  
})

function startTimer(dauer) {
  let timer = 5;

  zeit = setInterval(function() {
    display.textContent = parseInt(timer); // zeigt sekunden-variable

    --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab

    if (timer < 0.00) {

      timer = 5;
      console.log(timer);
      $("#start").fadeIn();
      $("#welcome").fadeIn();
      $("#time").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
      $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

      alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");

      klick = 0
      console.log(timer);



      clearInterval(zeit)

    } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet


  }, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)

};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
  let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) - 20 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker
  let zufal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) //Zufällige Variable für den Linkswert

  klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
  if (klick % 2 == 0) {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '0.3',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast"); //bewegt den Klick-Block auf eine zufällige Stelle
  } else {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '1.0',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast")

  }


});
```

```html
<div><span id="time"></span> </div>
<div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Wenn du bereit bist, klicke auf "Start"</div>
<button id="start" type=button>Start</button>
<button id="clicker" type=button>KLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use a StackOverflow snippet so that your code is runnable.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: It only has that behaviour from the second time you click start. I would assume from that behaviour you're not resetting your counter variable correctly when you clear the original timer.

Comment: You can click the `[<>]` button in the question editor. I've done it for you in this case

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan!

Comment: The problem appears to be that your `setInterval` function runs only every second - obviously that's what you wanted, but it means you have to wait a second even before the first time, which is when the variable is reset to 5 after reaching 0 the previous time.

Comment: add `display.textContent = "";` to start button click function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user @Robin Zigmond suggested, because you are using setInterval, you are waiting a second before you even run your interval each time.

A potential solution to this is surround your code in a function, call it first, and then set your interval.

I've attached a working solution below :

```js
let klick = 0;
display = document.querySelector('#time');

$("#start").click(function() { //clickfunktion beim starten.
  $("#start").fadeOut(); //Der Startbutton geht weg
  $("#welcome").fadeOut(); // Das Willkommensschild geht weg

  $("#time").fadeIn(900); //Timer kommt 
  $("#clicker").animate({
    height: 'toggle'
  }); //clicker wird gestartet 

  var dauer = 5;

  startTimer(dauer); //übergibt die variable dauer, und dass die Funktion gestartet wird.  
})

function startTimer(dauer) {
  let timer = 5;
  runTimer();
  zeit = setInterval(runTimer, 1000); //zahl gibt an, wie oft die Function pro zeit wiederholt wird. Hier eine Sekunde (1000Millisekunden)
  function runTimer(){
    display.textContent = parseInt(timer); // zeigt sekunden-variable

    --timer; //setzt den timer immer einen herab

    if (timer < 0.00) {

      timer = 5;
      console.log(timer);
      $("#start").fadeIn();
      $("#welcome").fadeIn();
      $("#time").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").fadeOut();
      $("#clicker").css("margin-top", "10%");
      $("#clicker").css("margin-left", "50%");

      alert("Sauber du hast " + klick + " klicks in 5 Sekunden geschafft!");

      klick = 0
      console.log(timer);

      clearInterval(zeit);

    } //wenn timer auf 0 ist, wird alles wieder angezeigt und die Interval-Function beendet

}
  

};

$("#clicker").click(function() {
  let zufall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) - 20 //setzt eine zufällige höhe für den clicker
  let zufal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45) //Zufällige Variable für den Linkswert

  klick = klick + 1 //setzt den zähler beim klicken eins hoch
  if (klick % 2 == 0) {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '0.3',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast"); //bewegt den Klick-Block auf eine zufällige Stelle
  } else {
    $("#clicker").animate({
      opacity: '1.0',
      left: zufall + "%",
      top: zufal + "%"
    }, "fast")

  }


});
```

```html
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div><span id="time"></span> </div>
<div id="welcome">Willkommen zu unserem Reaktionsspiel! Wenn du bereit bist, klicke auf "Start"</div>
<button id="start" type=button >Start</button>
<button id="clicker" type=button>KLICK</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Apologies, I do not speak the same language as the documentation, so the comments may be off.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @Christoph Apologies, error with the snippet. Amended.

Comment: This works for me! Thanks for your help, you don't have to worry about the language, I can handle that!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your counting mechanism is way too complicated. Here is a simplified version of what you are trying to achieve:

```js
let c = 0
document.getElementById('count').addEventListener('click', function() {
  c++
})
document.getElementById('timer').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let number = 5
  let interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('thenumber').innerHTML = number
    number--
    if (number == -1) {
      alert('You clicked: ' + c)
      c = 0
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<div id="thenumber"></div>
<button id="timer">klick me</button>
<button id="count">count</button>
```